# On Radio Select, show different checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a Javascript or jQuery solution, either works.

Anyway, when a user selects one of the choices for the radio buttons, I want a different set of checkboxes to show up. So, if a user chooses By Name, the name checkboxes will show up. And then when the user chooses By Title, the name checkboxes will disappear and the title checkboxes will show up.

When a page loads, and an option is not chosen, no checkboxes should appear

Here is what the HTML looks like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="selectType" value="byName" />By Name</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="selectType" value="byTitle" />By Title</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="selectName1" />Name 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="selectName1" />Name 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="selectTitle1" />Title 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="selectTitle2" />Title 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What would this code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use data attributes to reference groups of checkboxes. This way you can make your code really flexible and unobtrusive:

```
$('.type-check').change(function() {
    $('.type-group').hide().filter('.type-group-' + $(this).data('type')).show();
});
```

HTML sample:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="selectType" class="type-check" data-type="name" value="byName" /> By Name</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="selectType" class="type-check" data-type="title" value="byTitle" /> By Title</td>
</tr>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D8s9G/

Comment: very well. just one liner answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

First give your checkboxes classes..

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selectName1" class="name"/>Name 1
<input type="checkbox" name="selectName2" class="name"/>Name 2
```

do the same for titles and give them a class name of 'title' and for your radios too..

```
<input type="radio" name="selectType" value="byName" class="radioName" />
```

then;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.radioName').click(function () {
      $('.name').show();
      $('.title').hide();
   });

   //same logic for titles..
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution - http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/fkvSg/

**jQuery:**

```
$('.name').closest('tr').toggle(false);
$('.title').closest('tr').toggle(false);

$('input[name=selectType]').change(function () {
    var byNameSelected = $(this).val() == 'byName';
    $('.name').closest('tr').toggle(byNameSelected);
    $('.title').closest('tr').toggle(!byNameSelected);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="selectType" value="byName" />By Name</td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="selectType" value="byTitle" />By Title</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="name" name="selectName1" />Name 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="name" name="selectName2" />Name 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="title" name="selectTitle1" />Title 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="title" name="selectTitle2" />Title 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have added css classes to all the four checkboxes, so that the group of 'Name' and 'Title' checkboxes could be grouped.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the inputs with their name and show or hide the relevant inputs:

```
    $('input[value*="byName"]').click( function() {

    $('input[name*="selectName1"]').show();
    $('input[name*="selectTitle1"]').hide();
}

    $('input[value*="byTitle"]').click( function() {

    $('input[name*="selectName1"]').hide();
    $('input[name*="selectTitle1"]').show();
}
```